# Uppercase style name makes my app crash

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, android-styles

In my app, I have this set of styles in my XML files :

```
<style name="size0font">
    <item name="font_size">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="size1font">
    <item name="font_size">28sp</item>
</style>
```

I use them to change the font size application-wide with this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:textSize">?attr/font_size</item>
</style>
```

And `getTheme().applyStyle(R.style.size1font, false);` in `onCreate`

It works like a charm. But I have a very weird bug : if I rename the font styles to match the style naming conventions, e.g. `Size0Font` and `Size1Font`... the app crashes. There is a `NullPointerException` somewhere into the `getActionBar` method that I call in `onCreate`. It apparently comes from the first uppercase in the style name.

The full stack trace can be found there : https://pastebin.com/wZYKBYhQ

`CustomActionBarActivity.java:271` is `this.actionBar = getActionBar();`.

I test this on a Nougat Nexus 5X. Any clue on what is happening here ?

Comment: May be #BUG . Avoid use Uppercase

Comment: Yeah that's what I do for now but that's a weird bug